# How to handle HTTP Connect in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl, tcp

I would like to handle HTTP on very low level - at the moment I'm stuck with HTTP CONNECT verb. It looks like `HttpListener` doesn't have access to these request because they are handled somewhere inside HTTP API or HTTP.SYS. I'm able to handle such requests with native `TcpListener` but in such case I would lose all HTTP functionality = I would implement HTTP from scratch.

I also checked FiddlerCore but it also handles these requests on some Win API layer. Is there any pure .NET HTTP stack?

Edit: I'm working on HTTP proxy with some additional request analysis and statistics so I don't want to lose HTTP parsing and in the same time I want to know about SSL connections.

Comment: what do you mean by "pure .NET HTTP stack" - a stack implemented in .NET but NOT using HTTP.SYS etc. ? if yes there some 3rd-party stacks...

Comment: If you whould like to handle HTTP on very low level, you really will loose all HTTP functionality in Http* classes. What is the question?

Comment: Use TCP sockets if you want it to, use "winsock2.dll" interop calls form c#

Comment: BTW `HTTP CONNECT` is a verb for implementing HTTP proxy AFAIK - is this what you need to implement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Again the problem is not in API but in developer :)

I have some test suite to test my implementation but the test suite was connecting directly (not as to a proxy) - that was the first problem. The second problem was that this test suite should use `TcpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` if I want to test Connect verb separately because `HttpWebRequest` uses it only internally when using proxy for HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tcp* ans Socket*, not Http* related classes to use *really* low level in .NET.

TCP is at the bottom of HTTP protocol stack.

Use TCP sockets if you want it to, just use "winsock2.dll" interop calls form c#, and all related stuff like structure definitions etc, or use native C++

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are building your custom HTTP/HTTPS server or proxy and you don't mind third-party components, then our SecureBlackbox includes HTTP/HTTPS server components which let you do almost anything with any verb. Pure .NET, use any socket classes.